# How to trim strings with regular expression?

Tags: r

I have very large file names and I want to trim them.
the  file names are like this

```
dgfs_adf_vdsvs_sjfj_dbsd_vsdvv.txt
scs_adaca_vdscvs_fj_dsd_vsdvv.txt
```

I just want to keep the all expression between first dash and 4th dash which translate into:

```
adf_vdsvs_sjfj
adaca_vdscvs_fj
```

Would someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use sub,

```
x <- c("dgfs_adf_vdsvs_sjfj_dbsd_vsdvv.txt",
"scs_adaca_vdscvs_fj_dsd_vsdvv.txt")
sub("^.*?_(.*?_.*?_.*?)_.*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "adf_vdsvs_sjfj"  "adaca_vdscvs_fj"
```

`.*?` is non-greedy which stops matching util it finds the first match. So `^.*?_` will match all the chars upto the first underscore, likewise it goes on.

or

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "_"), function(x) paste(c(x[2],x[3],x[4]),collapse="_"))
[1] "adf_vdsvs_sjfj"  "adaca_vdscvs_fj"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "dgfs_adf_vdsvs_sjfj_dbsd_vsdvv.txt" # long name
y = unlist(strsplit(x, "_")) # split on "_" and make vector
z = paste(y[2], y[3], y[4], sep = "_")  # join elements 2-4
```